# How to implement SlowMotion and TimeLapse video recording using Camera API

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, frame-rate

Is there any way to implement Slow Motion and Time Lapse recording using Camera API?

I tried using `MediaRecorder` setting `VideoFrameRate`, `VideoBitRate` `VideoCaptureRate` but nothing work for me.

I have successfully implemented using JNI but i found it is taking too much time and not optimized as well.

If you find any other solution available please help me.

Comment: The two challenges are very different. While SlowMotion depends on high-FPS native camera support, TimeLapse can be performed with MediaCodec. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972081/how-to-drop-frames-while-recording-with-mediacodec-and-inputsurface and https://github.com/saki4510t/TimeLapseRecordingSample

Comment: Another open-source project is https://github.com/mercyorangi/sky-camera

Comment: @AlexCohn thank you for trying but above code doesn't work for me, in case of slow motion.

Comment: Absolutely. The links I gave were only about TimeLapse. There is no device-independent way to produce slow motion video, as far as I know. camera2 API can help, but it is fully supported on few recent devices only.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, do you know an android camera application (third-party) which already capture at 120 fps rate? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it myself and i am sharing my working code piece , just using Camera API slow motion and timelapse are implemented

Before start you must know definition of `setCaptureRate(double fps)`

> Set video frame capture rate.
>   This can be used to set a different video frame capture rate than the
>   recorded video's playback rate. This method also sets the recording
>   mode to time lapse. In time lapse video recording, only video is
>   recorded. Audio related parameters are ignored when a time lapse
>   recording session starts, if an application sets them.

**TimeLapse**
For time lapse you need to use following camera profile , According to you video frame width and height. *Choose any one from below profile* or you may choose other according to your need.

```
profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_1080P);

profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_720P);

profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_480P);
```

And now you need configure your video `setCaptureRate` and `setVideoEncodingBitRate`

```
video_recorder.setCaptureRate(profile.videoFrameRate/6.0f);
video_recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
```

and at last you need to set your configured Profile to your MediaRecorder.

```
video_recorder.setProfile(profile);
```

**Slow Motion**
For slow motion you also need to configure **CamcorderProfile** i am using following config for profile.

```
profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_HIGH);
 video_recorder.setCaptureRate(profile.videoFrameRate / 0.25f);
video_recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
video_recorder.setProfile(profile);
```

***For slowmotion you have to use CameraAPI2 otherwise it will not work.***

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, do you know an android camera application (third-party) which already capture at 120 fps rate? Thanks

Comment: Google Camera API 2 Sample capture 120fps. but API 2 depends on device hardware.