# Android Camera2, Support for high speed 960? (super slow motion, video)

Tags: android

I'm trying to adjust super-slow-motion durations on my Galaxy phone. Is this also possible in developer mode?

Is there any solution?

Comment: you need high refresh rate supported hardware then its possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176085/how-to-implement-slowmotion-and-timelapse-video-recording-using-camera-api this may help you

Comment: also check camerax library